# Label of theorems

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, labels

Is there an equivalent of `\figurename` for theorems and lemmas?

For instance, given that I've defined

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

and in the code I define an example and a figure, I would be happy to avoid using `Theorem~\ref`, in case I need to change it to a lemma:

```
\begin{theorem}
\label{th:first}
With reference to \figurename~\ref{fig:example}.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\label{th:second}
With reference to \figurename~\ref{fig:example} and \theoremname~\ref{th:first}
\end{theorem}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cleveref` is your friend here -- no need to define a `\theoremname` here -- it's defined by `cleveref` for many use - cases already.

Use `\cref` for lower case names and `\Cref` for upper case names.

For special names there is no clue for `\cleveref` to provide the correct name initially, in this case use the setup commands `\crefname` and `\Crefname`.

The `\crefname` and `\Crefname` for `example` are not needed here, since `cleveref` defines them for `example` already, but perhaps not in any language desired or it's necessary to use another `theorem`, say `footheorem` -- this is not predefined, so I decided to show how it could be done.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\usepackage{cleveref}


% Not really needed!
\crefname{example}{example}{examples} 
\Crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\caption{foo}\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\begin{theorem}
\label{th:first}
With reference to \cref{fig:example}.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\label{th:second}
With reference to \Cref{fig:example} and \Cref{th:first}, but see \Cref{ex:first} also
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
\label{ex:first}
With reference to \Cref{fig:example} and \Cref{th:first}. 
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]